# How to print conditional statement in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to add the below conditional statement of mine which converts one GMT offset date string  column into MST .

Sample input

```
07/Sep/2020:11:28:01 +0000!@44.20.20.1!@TestDevice
```

Sample output

```
07/Sep/2020:04:28:01 -7000!@44.20.20.1!@TestDevice
```

This conditional statement works fine

```
STR='07/Sep/2020:11:28:01 +0000'; SUB='+000'; if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then STR="${STR//\// }"; STR="${STR/:/ }"; TZ="MST" date --date="$STR" +'%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'; else echo "$STR"; fi
```

I want to place the above conditional logic while extracting data from a file called output.csv with delimiter as "!@" and dump to output2.csv.So i need to put the above conditional logic in place of $1 in below statement

```
awk -F "\!@" '{print $1"\!@"substr($2,1,200)"\!@"$3}' output.csv >output2.csv
```

So I am trying it like this but it isnt working

```
STR=$1
awk -F "\!@" '{print $STR='07/Sep/2020:11:28:01 +0000'; SUB='+000'; if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then STR="${STR//\// }"; STR="${STR/:/ }"; TZ="MST" date --date="$STR" +'%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'; else echo "$STR"; fi"\!@"substr($2,1,200)"\!@"$3}' output.csv >output2.csv
```

Can someone please help

Comment: Could you please add sample of input and sample of expected output more clearly so that we could better understand the problem, special thanks for adding your efforts in question.

Comment: Can you describe in words what is it that you want to do. It is not clear from the combined awk/bash what is it that you want to do.

Comment: Hi i have updated with input and output data

Comment: `awk -F '!@' -v OFS='!@' '$1~/[0-9A-Za-z /:+-]/{gsub("/"," ",$1);sub(":"," ",$1);"TZ=MST date --date=\""$1"\" +\"%d/%h/%Y:$H:$M:$S %z\""|getline d;print d,substr($2,1,200),$3}' output.csv >output2.csv`

Comment: @jhnc -This isnt working. ..I am getting 07/Sep/2020::: -0700!@44.20.20.1!@TestDevice
The HH:MM:SS is gone

Comment: `$H` should be `%H`, etc

Comment: Can u please use my logic STR='07/Sep/2020:11:28:01 +0000'; SUB='+000'; if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then STR="${STR//\// }"; STR="${STR/:/ }"; TZ="MST" date --date="$STR" +'%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'; else echo "$STR"; fi
and place in $1 position?

Comment: `awk -F '!@' -v OFS='!@' '$1!~/[+]000/{print;next} $1~/[0-9A-Za-z /:+-]/{gsub("/"," ",$1);sub(":"," ",$1);"TZ=MST date --date=\""$1"\" +\"%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z\""|getline d;print d,substr($2,1,200),$3}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '!@' -v OFS='!@' '$1~/[0-9A-Za-z /:+-]/{gsub("/"," ",$1);sub(":"," ",$1);"TZ=MST date --date=\""$1"\" +\"%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z\""|getline d;print d,substr($2,1,200),$3}' output.csv >output2.csv
```

This worked.Thanks jhnc